# How to Customizing JAXBContext Unmarshaller for complex case

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have issue about convert XML to Java Object , in here i use JAXB.
in my case:

XML DATA :

```
<persons>
  <person>
     <name>Aris Tonar</name>
     <age />
     <nickname />
     <saldo />
  </person>
</persons>
```

JAVA CLASS OF XML DATA :

```
public class Person{
   private String name;
   private Integer age;
   private String nickName;
   private Integer id;
   private Double saldo;

   /**
   *Setter and Getter
   */

}
```

and when i using standard JAXBContext Unmarshaller code for parse it to Java Object. with code :

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class.getPackage().getName());
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
JAXBElement element = (JAXBElement) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(stringOfXmlData.toString())));
Person obj = (Person) element.getValue();
```

it will give result :
Person name = "Aris Tonar"
Person age = null
Person nickname = ""
Person id = null
Person saldo = null

but not that result what i want,  i want JAXB will give result :

Person name = "Aris Tonar"
Person age = 0
Person nickname = ""
Person id = null
Person saldo = 0

1. i want every element which declared in XML DATA will : if it's value specified jaxb will interpreting it as normal(like name element) but if it's value not specified jaxb will interpreting it as default value(like age,nickname, saldo elements)
2. and if element not declared in XML Data, so jaxb will interpreting it as null.(like id element)

whether possible i do it? may be with customizing JAXBContext Code ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@XmlType(name = "person", propOrder = {"name", "age", "nickName" , "saldo"})
public class Person {

private String name;
private Integer age;
private String nickName;
private Integer id;
private Double saldo;

public Person(String name, Integer age, String nickName, Integer id, Double saldo) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.nickName = nickName;
  this.id = id;
  this.saldo = saldo;
}

public Person() {
  //jaxb constructor
}

@XmlElement(defaultValue="0")
public Integer getAge() {
  return age;
}

@XmlTransient
public Integer getId() {
  return id;
}

@XmlElement(defaultValue="")
public String getName() {
  return name;
}

@XmlElement(name="nickname" , defaultValue="")
public String getNickName() {
 return nickName;
}

@XmlElement(defaultValue="0")
public Double getSaldo() {
  return saldo;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
  this.age = age;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}

public void setNickName(String nickName) {
  this.nickName = nickName;
}

public void setSaldo(Double saldo) {
  this.saldo = saldo;
}


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Err, your Explanation is my solution,,

Comment: hallo Err, i have other issue.. 
My Java Class and also it's xml annotation in that class is result of JAXB Binding from xsd file,  in my case JAXB Binding define '@XmlAttribute' for a property, so how i can assign defaultValue for that property.

Thanks

Comment: you set the default value in the xsd file. `<xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" default="EN"/>`

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit cumbersome but you should be able to achieve what you want using type adapters:

```
public class Person{
   private String name;
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(IntegerZeroDefaultAdapter.class)
   @XmlSchemaType(name = "integer")
   private Integer age;
   private String nickName;
   private Integer id;
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DoubleZeroDefaultAdapter.class)
   @XmlSchemaType(name = "double")
   private Double saldo;
   // ...    
}

public class IntegerZeroDefaultAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Integer> {
  public String marshal(Integer n) {
    return String.valueOf(n);
  }

  public Integer unmarshal(String val) {
    if(val == null) return null;
    else if("".equals(val)) return 0;
    else return Integer.valueOf(val);
  }
}

// likewise for DoubleZeroDefaultAdapter
```

You don't need an adapter for name or nickname unless the default value you want to use is something other than the empty string - the default for string values is that a missing element means `null` and a specified-but-empty element means the empty string, remember that in XML `<nickname />` is exactly equivalent to `<nickname></nickname>`.

Comment: Though on re-reading the docs, I would say Err's answer using `@XmlElement(defaultValue = "...")` is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Ian Roberts, although Err's answer more simple, but your explanation is my solution for handle complex element like java.util.Date or other not wrapper class(Custom Class).

Answer (score 1):

if you instantiate your members with default values when you declare them, you should fix the first problem.

Try:

```
public class Person{
 private String name = "";
 private Integer age = 0;
 private String nickName; = ""
 private Integer id = 0;
 private Double saldo =0.0;
```

hth,
mcalex

Answer (score 0):

I you use cxf-codegen-plugin, you can (starting from XSD/WSDL)

1. Setup up the default value within the XSD of your data model ("default" keyword on each type)
2. Use the cxf-xjc-dv extension to the plugin to handle default values in getters of the generated classes.

This will for instance create a getter to your field age like this:

```
public Integer getAge() {
   if (age == null)
      return new Interger(0);
   return age;
}
```

Comment: This is the reverse of what the OP wants, though, as this will return default values for elements that are _not_ specified in the XML and empty string/null values for elements that _are_ specified but have an empty value.  OP wants specified-but-empty -> default and unspecified -> `null`.